# module 'subprocess' has no attribute '_subprocess'

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, subprocess

I used python3.7 in windows7.
When I tried to run this line: `suinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`
error occurs: module 'subprocess' has no attribute '_subprocess'

```
import os
import sqlite3
import subprocess
import time
import re
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse   


suinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
suinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

How to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `subprocess._subprocess`, the constant is straight under `subprocess`:

```
suinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW